# An issue with replace function

Tags: php, replace

I'm doing search engine for games titles in my database and I have some issue with that.

First, here's the look on DB:

```
ID   TITLE
1     aaB
2     abc
3     ABC
4     AbdedABc
5     deff
```

Next, I'm doing this query:

```
SELECT g.title FROM game g WHERE g.title LIKE '%abc%'
```

All I want to do, is to print out all titles like this (with bold matches):

```
abc // match
ABC // match
Abded ABc // match last part, space added for clarity
```

For now, my script returns this:

```
str_replace('abc', '<b>abc</b>', $row['title'])

abc // matches
ABC
AbdedABc
```

Someone know any algorithm (or other way) to do not change letters upper/lower case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you wan't to do but to match any combination of `abc` in upper or lowercase and make it bold you can do like this:

```
 $data = "testABC";
 echo preg_replace("/(abc)/i","<bold>$1</bold>",$data);
```

Comment: I think the bold part had to do with how the OP was asking the question, not what they were trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a case-sensitive replace then? Look at [str_ireplace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php).